# Where did the seventh minister sleep?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Megila says that there were six golden and silver beds on a alabaster floor " מִטּוֹת זָהָב וָכֶסֶף עַל רִצְפַת בַּהַט וָשֵׁשׁ"

However there were seven ministers as it says "שבעת רואי פני המלך"

Where did the seventh minister sleep?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5):

I asked someone in Shul this morning and he told me that the seven ministers were כַּרְשְׁנָא שֵׁתָר אַדְמָתָא תַרְשִׁישׁ, מֶרֶס מַרְסְנָא, מְמוּכָן. Obviously Admasa was called Admasa as he did not have a bed and slept on the ground.